# Where can I find the coverage.em with aosp project?

Tags: java, android, code-coverage, jacoco, emma

To work with emma to generate the code coverage report, I need two files, coverage.em and coverage.ec.

And then use

`java -cp emma.jar emma report -r html -in coverage.ec -sp src -in coverage.em` to covert coverage.ec to get the html files.

I work with a project which is built with the Android.mk in the aosp.

My project is compiled with `mm -B`.

coverage.ec is generated in `/data/data/com.my.app/files/` after the instrumentation.

I can not find coverage.em in `aosp_project/out/target/common/obj/APPS/                     myapp_intermediates/` after `mm -B`

Only `aosp_project/out/target/common/obj/APPS/                     myapp_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar` is generated, but I do not know how to use it.

Where is the coverage.em in the aosp?

Thank you